# Why does counsel-find-file use the current Dired directory when I specify argument INITIAL-DIRECTORY?

Tags: dired, counsel

I am trying to use `counsel-find-file` to open the folder containing my Emacs configuration through a call such as the following:

```
(counsel-find-file 'nil "~/Documents/test-emacs/.emacs.d/")
```

This seems to work fine for the most part except when I am in a dired buffer. When I invoke the command from the dired buffer, `counsel-find-file` always opens the minibuffer into the directory that dired is in, not `~/Documents/test-emacs/.emacs.d`.

I have attempted to invoke this command through both a `general.el`-configured key binding, and through `M-:`. Both methods produce the same results. Can someone explain why this happens and how to obtain the desired behavior of directing the minibuffer to `~/Documents/test-emacs/.emacs.d`?

Comment: There's never any reason to quote `nil`. It evaluates to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Counsel.  But from a quick look at its code:

It looks like `counsel-find-file` binds `default-directory` to use the `INITIAL-DIRECTORY` argument, but if the current buffer is in Dired mode then that binding is *overridden* to use the value of `dired-current-directory` instead.

And that function returns the value of the directory for the listing you are currently in in Dired. (E.g., if you are in a subdir listing then that subdir is used, else the top-level dir is used.)

```lisp
(defun counsel--find-file-1 (prompt initial-input action caller)
  (let ((default-directory
         (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode) ; <================
             (dired-current-directory)   ; <================
           default-directory)))
    ...))
```

[FWIW, I suspect the author of Counsel might want to change that `(eq major-mode 'dired-mode)` to use `derived-mode` instead. But that's unrelated to your question/problem.]

So the directory used in `counsel--find-file-1` is the value of `dired-current-directory` from your current position in Dired.

This binding of `default-directory` in `counsel-find-file` is overridden by the binding in `counsel--find-file-1`:

```lisp
(let ((tramp-archive-enabled nil)
      (default-directory (or initial-directory default-directory)))
  ...)
```

You'll notice, by the way, that the doc of `counsel-find-file` doesn't even mention argument `INITIAL-DIRECTORY`:

> Forward to `find-file`.
>
> When `INITIAL-INPUT` is non-`nil`, use it in the minibuffer during completion.

If it did, it would probably have to tell you something about its use, including the fact that it's apparently useless when in Dired.

Dunno whether this is a misfeature, a bug, or a feature. If you don't get a good answer here from someone else, and you think it perhaps shouldn't behave this way, consider reporting it to the Counsel maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for tracing this. I was able to get the desired behavior by rewriting that function to take the dired portion out. Still fairly new to Emacs hacking, so I don't know if this practice is frowned upon, or if this will break anything else...suppose I'll try it out for a while.